# Java program not receiving/sending information to/from server/client

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

I'm trying to write a simple chat program with a server and a single client. I can connect them together just fine with port forwarding and they can each receive a single message. However, once they connect, I want to to be able to send and receive messages at the same time. For some reason this isn't happening at all. Here's my code.

Client:

```
// Client class
public class Client
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    // Get server name, port number, and username from command line
    String serverName = args[0];
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    String username = args[2];
    try
    {
        // Print welcome message and information
        System.out.println("Hello, " + username);
        System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
        // Create the socket
        Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
        // Print connected information
        System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        // Out to server
        OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
        // Print message to server
        out.writeUTF("Hello from " + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
        // In from server
        InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
        // Print message from server
        System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
        // Begin reading user input to send to the server
        Scanner chat = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lineTo;
        String lineFrom;
        // Keep the program open unless the user types endchat
        while (!chat.nextLine().equals("endchat"))
        {
            // Read any messages coming in from the server          
            lineFrom = String.valueOf(in.readUTF());
            System.out.println(lineFrom);
            // Write any messages to the client
            lineTo = chat.nextLine();
            out.writeUTF(lineTo);
        }
        // Close the connection
        client.close();
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Server:

```
// Server class
public class Server extends Thread
{
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private String username;

// Create server
public Server(int port, String username) throws IOException
{
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    this.username = username;
}
// Keep running
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        // Print info
        System.out.println("Hello, " + username);
        System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
        // Accept the client
        Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
        // To client
        OutputStream outToClient = server.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out =  new DataOutputStream(outToClient);
        // From client
        InputStream inFromClient = server.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromClient);
        // Print info when connected
        System.out.println("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());         
        // Print message from client
        System.out.println("Client says: " + in.readUTF());
        // Print message to client
        out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to " + server.getLocalSocketAddress());
        // Tell client they may begin chatting
        out.writeUTF("You may now begin chatting! Type endchat to end the chat!");
        // Start reading user input
        Scanner chat = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lineFrom;
        String lineTo;
        // Keep the program open as long as the user doesn't type endchat
        while (!chat.nextLine().equals("endchat"))
        {
            // Read from client
            lineFrom = String.valueOf(in.readUTF());
            System.out.println(lineFrom);
            // Send to client
            lineTo = chat.nextLine();               
            out.writeUTF(lineTo + "\n");
        }
    }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
    {
        System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    // Get port number and username from command line
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    String username = args[1];
    try
    {
        // Create and start new Server
        Thread t = new Server(port, username);
        t.start();
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

EDIT: I added the newline character to my Server class when a message is sent. I'm now receiving the message in my Client class but the message I'm getting is in weird characters.

Comment: As far as I understand from your code, in order for server to print the messages coming from the client, you need to type something on the server side, too. Are you aware of that?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I'll be fixing it eventually and modularizing my code as myqyl4 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

First separate out your read and write into distinct methods

i.e.

```
private String read(Server server){
// From client
        InputStream inFromClient = server.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromClient);
.....
 return message
}

private void write(Server server, String message){
 OutputStream outToClient = server.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out =  new DataOutputStream(outToClient);
```

......
    }

Now use you main/run method to switch between read/write.
If the client writes, the it should wait for a read response and same with the server.

and you can do this while "endChat" is not true.

This is simplistic but it should get you going.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I was planning on doing that eventually. I think my problem has to do with inserting the newline character. Please see my updated Server class. I can now receive messages in my client class, but they come in weird characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to send and receive messages at the same time.

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            while (!chat.nextLine().equals("endChat")){
                System.out.println(in.readUTF());
            }
        }catch(Exception error){error.printStackTrace();}
    }
}.start();

new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            while (!chat.nextLine().equals("endChat")){
                out.writeUTF(chat.nextLine());
            }
        }catch(Exception error){error.printStackTrace();}
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't like the brackets after Thread() and before .start(); Is this proper syntax?

Comment: Inside the brackets there has to be a public void run(){//put code here}, I must have forgot to put that in my answer, I'll edit it in. Sorry it took me so long to respond